# Crossbar.io - WAMP router not working

Tags: node.js, autobahn, wamp-protocol, crossbar

I have followed this instruction http://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-started-with-NodeJS/ and I can access to frontend via `localhost:8080`, but seem like hello.js in backend side had not been executed. This is the log after I run `crossbar start`:

> 2014-10-30 23:52:33+0700 [Controller  48946] Log opened.
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:33+0700 [Controller  48946] ============================== Crossbar.io ==============================
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:33+0700 [Controller  48946] Crossbar.io 0.9.9 starting
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:34+0700 [Controller  48946] Running on CPython using KQueueReactor reactor
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:34+0700 [Controller  48946] Starting from node directory /Users/toannguyen/Documents/Local-Repo/crossbar-hello/.crossbar
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:34+0700 [Controller  48946] Starting from local configuration '/Users/toannguyen/Documents/Local-Repo/crossbar-hello/.crossbar/config.json'
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:34+0700 [Controller  48946] No WAMPlets detected in enviroment.
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:34+0700 [Controller  48946] Starting Router with ID 'worker1' ..
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:35+0700 [Router      48950] Log opened.
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Router      48950] Running under CPython using KQueueReactor reactor
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Router      48950] Entering event loop ..
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Router with ID 'worker1' and PID 48950 started
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Router 'worker1': realm 'realm1' started
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Router 'worker1': role 'role1' started on realm 'realm1'
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Router      48950] Site starting on 8080
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Router 'worker1': transport 'transport1' started
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Starting Guest with ID 'worker2' ..
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] GuestWorkerClientProtocol.connectionMade
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Guest with ID 'worker2' and PID 48951 started
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Warning: cannot watch directory for changes - feature DirWatcher unavailable
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Guest 'worker2': started
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] Upon execvpe /usr/bin/node ['/usr/bin/node', 'hello.js'] in environment id 4347382592
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] :Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 403, in _fork
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] path, uid, gid, executable, args, environment)
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 453, in _execChild
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] os.execvpe(executable, args, environment)
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 355, in execvpe
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] _execvpe(file, args, env)
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 370, in _execvpe
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] func(file, *argrest)
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Guest       48951] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] GuestWorkerClientProtocol.connectionLost: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 1.
>       ]
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] GuestWorkerClientProtocol: guest ended with error 1
>
> 2014-10-30 23:52:36+0700 [Controller  48946] Guest excited with error [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 1.
>       ]

Then although frontend keeps publishing on channel 'onhello', but server has not received and logged anything. What is the errors and could anyone help me to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crossbar.io cannot find the NodeJS executable. It needs the fully qualified path in the `config.json`.

E.g. on Ubuntu, NodeJS is installed under `/usr/bin/nodejs`, and to make that work with the Crossbar.io node configuration generated by default, you need to do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

so you get

```
oberstet@ubuntu1404:~/temp/node4$ ls -la /usr/bin/node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Okt 31 09:35 /usr/bin/node -> /usr/bin/nodejs
oberstet@ubuntu1404:~/temp/node4$ ls -la /usr/bin/nodejs 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1462424 Mär 27  2014 /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use Mac OS X and notice the Node executable is under /usr/local/bin. Changing the path in config.json and everything work